# how to search from an array? (i have a problem when i'm searching an array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i have a problem when i'm searching an array (@doweets is the array, array with Doweet objects, Doweet is like status...)

how can i do the same search like here:

```
    doweets = Doweet.where(:date => time1..time2)
```

on variable of array? when i write like this i get an error:

```
    doweets = @doweets.where(:date => time1..time2)
```

what to do, to do it with select? how can i do it?

thanks guys,

gal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but it should look a bit like this:

```
doweets = @doweets.select{|d| d.date>=time1 && d.date<=time2}
```

Answer (score 0):

`where` is a method of `Relation`. Don't use `all` to return all results as `Array`. You can add finder methods as chain, and the query is executed when results are required, i.e., `each`, `first` or `all` are invoked. For `Array`, you should use `find_all` to search.

FYI:

- [ActiveRecord Query Interface](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)
- [Module Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html)